# Dynamic class creation with type and __slots__?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, dynamic

When creating result objects within a class, is it possible to use `__slots__` in this example?  I thought I could get it to work by passing `'__slots__'` into the dictionary for the third argument to `type`:

```
class GeocodeResult(object):
    """class to handle Reverse Geocode Result"""

    __slots__ = ['geometry', 'response', 'spatialReference',
                'candidates', 'locations', 'address', 'type', 'results']

    def __init__(self, res_dict, geo_type):
        RequestError(res_dict)
        self.response = res_dict
        self.type = 'esri_' + geo_type
        self.spatialReference = None
        self.candidates = []
        self.locations = []
        self.address = []
        if 'spatialReference' in self.response:
            self.spatialReference = self.response['spatialReference']

        # more stuff

    @property
    def results(self):
        results = []
        for result in self.address + self.candidates + self.locations:
            result['__slots__'] = ['address', 'score', 'location', 'attributes']
            results.append(type('GeocodeResult.result', (object,), result))
        return results

    def __len__(self):
        """get length of results"""
        return len(self.results)
```

For the `results` property, I want to build a list of small, light-weight objects with 4 properties: `['address', 'score', 'location', 'attributes']`

The resulting object is created, and I can even get at the slots, but it is still keeping the `__dict__`.  Since there could potentially be hundreds of result objects, I want only the four properties listed above to save space.

Example:

```
>>> rev = GeocodeResult(r, 'reverseGeocode')
>>> result = rev.results[0]
>>> result.__slots__
['address', 'score', 'location', 'attributes']
>>> hasattr(result, '__dict__')
True
>>>
```

Is there a better way of doing this?  Or do I have to define an explicit class to handle this?

Comment: !! NOTE !! -- This answer is incorrect.  See the other answer here for a method to dynamically create classes with slots.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's totally possible to dynamically create classes with slots:

```
>>> C = type('C', (), {'__slots__': ('a', 'b')})
>>> C.a
<member 'a' of 'C' objects>
>>> dir(C())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'a', 'b']
>>> vars(C())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
TypeError: vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute
```

Works in Python 3 and 2.

You're seeing `hasattr(result, '__dict__')` evaluate `True` in your example because the list returned by `GecodeResult.results` is a list of types, not a list of instances. If you were to say `result().__dict__`, you would get an `AttributeError`.

(Also worth noting: each type in that list shares the name "GeocodeResult.result", but they are *not* the same type! `results[0].__class__ == results[1].__class__` is `False`.)

As jonrsharpe noted, it's better to just define the type once and reuse it, and namedtuple is perfect for the job, so stick with that :)

Comment: Interesting, this is good to know.  Thanks for sharing!  And yes, I am still sticking with the `namedtuple`, it is working nicely for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you *need* to create it dynamically; why not define the class with `__slots__` once, as they all appear to be the same, and just return a list of instances?

Alternatively, I would be inclined to use a [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) for this; they're pretty lightweight and still give access to their contents by attribute:

```
class GeocodeResult(object):
    """class to handle Reverse Geocode Result"""

    ...

    Result = namedtuple(
        'Result', 
        'address score location attributes',
    )

    @property
    def results(self):
        results = []
        for result in self.address + self.candidates + self.locations:
            results.append(self.Result(...))  # pass in the four relevant attributes
        return result

    ...
```

You could simplify the property a bit with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), too.

Comment: This worked nicely!  I was able to reduce the size dramatically of the result objects by using the namedtuple.  Thank you!

Comment: Even thought the docs state this, an inspection of the resulting object does not seem to reflect this.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven and the accepted answer says as much; that was posted a few years later, maybe something changed, but I've removed the inaccurate part.